# SSH connection getting closed automatically after a sudo command

Tags: ssh, rhel, sudo

I have two servers running the same version of RedHat 6.4, however one of them behaves differently when I run remote `sudo` commands through SSH on it. On server1, the connection is automatically closed after a **successful** `sudo` command, but on server3, the connection is kept open.

Note that for these tests the `sudo` user had the NOPASSWD flag so no prompt is asked. As far as I know, all configurations on these servers are the same (they were cloned).

I tested using this:

```
ssh -vvv user@server1 << EOF
sudo ls -l /home/
ls -l /home/
pwd
EOF
```

If I run this on server1 I get a single file listing.

```
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 1621
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
```

Running without the `sudo` command on the same server I get my two file listing and the `pwd` result

```
ssh -vvv user@server1 << EOF
ls -l /home/
ls -l /home/
pwd
EOF
```

Result:

```
debug3: Wrote 32 bytes for a total of 1605
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
total 40
drwxr-xr-x.  5 user       user       4096 Apr 26  2013 user
/home/user
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
```

However, running the script **with** the `sudo` command on **server3** I get the result of all 3 commands like the previous test. I compared the output of the `ssh -vvv` logs from both servers (1 and 3) and everything seems the same except for a debug line in a different order when the connection is closed (see `client_input...` line).

server1 (same with or without `sudo`)

```
[command results]
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
```

server3

```
[command results]
debug2: channel 0: rcvd eof
debug2: channel 0: output open -> drain
debug2: channel 0: obuf empty
debug2: channel 0: close_write
debug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug2: channel 0: rcvd close
```

I would like to know how to fix server1 so that the connection isn't automatically closed so that my script can execute completely when including `sudo` commands.

Some options I already checked:

- SE Linux is disabled
- The `passwd` file is properly configured with the `/bin/bash` shell
- errexit is off (command is successful anyway)
- `sudoers` and `sshd_config` configuration is the same between the two servers

The only difference between the servers I see is that the buggy server1 is an older generation of server, it's a ProLiant DL380 **G7** compared to a **G8** for server3. Other servers I've tried and that are working are also G8 (I only have one G7 to try on). I don't see how the hardware can cause that type of issue.

Comment: I wonder if errexit is being set?

Comment: also, compare the `/etc/sudoers` files (including `/etc/sudoers.d/*`), keeping an eye out for any `requiretty` or `!requiretty` differences.  Perhaps server3 has been configured to allow sudo without requiring a `tty`, and server1 has not.  One way to test would be to modify the server 1 command from `ssh -vvv user@server1 ...` to `ssh -t -vvv user@server1...`.  The `-t` option will force the allocation of a tty.  If sudo works doing that, then it's a tty requirement stuffing you up.

Comment: errexit is off (command is successful anyway). `requiretty` is commented out in the sudoers file and `sudoers.d` directory is empty.

Comment: I tried adding the `ssh -t ...` and I have the same issue.

Comment: `sshd_config` files are identical between servers. The user has a shell in `passwd`. `sudoers` configuration is the same between the servers.

Comment: I checked and the MAC addresses are different.

Comment: What if you replace your sudo command with `sudo id`

Comment: Same behavior. The id returned is root.